# How to build DNN Search Document Object when using a template which fetches information from an ERP System

Tags: search, dotnetnuke

We have a custom DNN Detailed Products View module which will fetch products when it loads. Which product it loads depends on the SKU in the URL query. For example www.mysite.com/SKU?=BG3000

In the Codebehind in the view.ascx.cs, I set the Meta Keywords, Title, and Description.

```
 var page = (DotNetNuke.Framework.CDefault)this.Page;
                page.Title = ProductDetails.MetaTitle;

                ///Set the metatag information for SEO - Added - ZR 05/07/2017
                ((DotNetNuke.Framework.CDefault)this.Page).Title = ProductDetails.MetaTitle;
                ((DotNetNuke.Framework.CDefault)this.Page).Description = ProductDetails.MetaDesc;
                ((DotNetNuke.Framework.CDefault)this.Page).KeyWords = ProductDetails.MetaKeywords;
```

How can I build the Search Object and Return it in the FeatureController.cs?
I currently have searchdoc within Search Documents. How will DNN crawl all my different products If I use this same module for every single product?

This is my current code:

```
    public class FeatureController : ModuleSearchBase
{

    public CommonDataDefinitions.Products.WebProductDetails ProductDetails { get; set; } = null;


    public override IList<SearchDocument> GetModifiedSearchDocuments(ModuleInfo moduleInfo, DateTime beginDateUtc)
    {

        var searchDocuments = new List<SearchDocument>
        {
            searchdoc
        };

        return searchDocuments;

        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```